# Calculate percent identity between two already-aligned sequences

Tags: python, optimization, bioinformatics

I have two strings in a file like this:

```
>1
atggca---------gtgtggcaatcggcacat
>2
atggca---------gtgtggcaatcggcacat
```

Using the AlignIO function in Biopython:

```
from Bio import AlignIO
print AlignIO.read("neighbor.fas", "fasta")
```

returns this:

```
SingleLetterAlphabet() alignment with 2 rows and 33 columns
atggca---------gtgtggcaatcggcacat 1
atggca---------gtgtggcaatcggcacat 2
```

I want to calculate the percentage identity between the two rows in this alignment.

```
row = align[:,n]
```

allows for the extraction of individual columns that can be compared.

Columns that contain only "-" should not be counted.

Comment: Have you profiled the code yet?

Comment: You are using non existing `line` variable.

Comment: @ChristopherMedrela sorry, I fixed that!

Comment: @Daenyth: I have not (do not know what that means)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script

Comment: Did you tried to access elements of align directly (`align[row, column]`) instead of creating a 1x2 matrix for each column?

Comment: BTW It looks like `row` is actually a column. And you should use `r` instead of `row` inside inner for loop.

Comment: If the strings you're comparing might be shifted, then you may want to compare their [Levenshtein distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) - you'll probably be able to find Python code for this.

Comment: IMO it's not a bioinformatics problem but only a string problem (you try to find the distance between two strings). You might take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/python-string-similarity-with-probability

Answer (score 3):

This is a fast but not biologically accurate answer.

use Levenshtein Python extension and C library.

http://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/

The Levenshtein Python C extension module contains functions for fast computation of - Levenshtein (edit) distance, and edit operations - string similarity - approximate median strings, and generally string averaging - string sequence and set similarity It supports both normal and Unicode strings.

Since these sequences are strings, why not!

```
sudo pip install python-Levenshtein
```

then fire up ipython:

```
In [1]: import Levenshtein

In [3]: Levenshtein.ratio('atggca---------gtgtggcaatcggcacat'.replace('-',''),
                          'atggca---------gtgtggcaatcggcacat'.replace('-','')) * 100
Out[3]: 100.0

In [4]: Levenshtein.ratio('atggca---------gtgtggcaatcggcacat'.replace('-',''),
                          'atggca---------gtgtggcaatcggcacaa'.replace('-','')) * 100
Out[4]: 95.83333333333334
```

Comment: This doesn't work. E.g. 
`Levenshtein.ratio('atggca---------gtgtggcaatcggcacat'.replace('-',''),
 'atggca---------gtgtggcaatcggcacta'.replace('-','')) * 100` gives 95.834 instead of 91.667 because there are two substitutions. Seems like Levenstein distance allows transposition of adjacent characters? Unsure.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to extend it to more than two sequences the following works well, it gives the same result as the BioPerl overall_percentage_identity function (http://search.cpan.org/dist/BioPerl/Bio/SimpleAlign.pm).

```
from Bio import AlignIO

align = AlignIO.read("neighbor.fas", "fasta")
print perc_identity(align)

def perc_identity(aln):
    i = 0
    for a in range(0,len(aln[0])):
        s = aln[:,a]
        if s == len(s) * s[0]:
            i += 1
    return 100*i/float(len(aln[0]))
```

Comment: This is very cool code.  I can tell you're from a Perl background (minimalist). Its the len(s) * s[0] that's slick, should be fast.

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is old but, since you are already in biopython, couldn't you just move along with the BLAST record class (chapter 7 of the tutorial http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html)?

I believe the option you need (under "7.4 The BLAST record class") is "hsp.identities".

Comment: please provide some explanation with your answer.